# Finding elapsed time across midnight without dates

Tags: python, datetime, time, timedelta

How would I compute the elapsed time between `time1 = 23:30:00` and `time2 = 01:30:00`? They do not have dates associated with them, but python attaches the date 1900-01-01 when I make them into datetime objects, so it would become `time1 = 1900-01-01 23:30:00` and `time2 = 1900-01-01 01:30:00`. My desired outcome would be 2 hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can subtract 2 datetime objects and get the difference between them

```
from datetime import datetime

# d = datetime(year, month, day, hour, min, sec)
d1 = datetime(2017, 9, 1, 23, 30, 00)
d2 = datetime(2017, 9, 2, 1, 30, 00)
print d2 - d1
```

2:00:00